# how to find Substring without builtin function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, substring, substr

I am trying to rebuilt Substring function. here is my code.it doesn't work when passed single parameter and also when num1> num2 .Can anyone tell me where should i change?

here is my code......

```js
function myFunction(num1, num2) {
  var str = "This is a string";
  var subString = "";
  var len = str.length;

  if (num1 < 0 || num2 > len) {
    console.log("Invalid input");
  } else {
    var k = 0;
    for (i = num1; i < num2; i++) {
      subString = subString + str[i];
      k++;
    }
    console.log(subString);
  }
}
myFunction(0, 4);
```

Comment: What do you mean by change, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I recommend checking the source code to see how JS actually does it.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to pass the string as a param as well, ```myFunction(str, start, end) {``` and your question belongs here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it doesn't work when passed single parameter and also when start > end

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a proper function name and singnature by using the string, start and end index as parameters.

Then start with an empty string and iterate from start to the end or the length of the string.

```js
function substring(string, start, end) {
    var result = '',
        length = Math.min(string.length, end),
        i = start;
  
    while (i < length) result += string[i++];
    return result;
}

console.log(substring('This is a string', 0, 4));
console.log(substring('This is a string', 40, 4));
```

Comment: shouldn't this question be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what happen when user input single parameter and also start > end ?

Comment: it returns an empty string. but you could add a check before and thrpw an exception or other hint.

Comment: yes but builtin js function substr() desen't return empty string in this situation. it return something else. i want to know that part of code.

Comment: just copy this part: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#Polyfill

Comment: @JuniusL. Only working code goes to CodeReview, we closed a copy of this question as off topic. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232151/14625

Answer (score 0):

Many roads lead to Rome. Here are three of them:

```js
function substring1(str, start, end) {
  return str
    .split("")
    .reduce((acc, val, i) => acc + (i >= start && i < end ? val : ""), "");
}

function substring2(str, start, end) {
  let substr = "";
  while (--end >= start) {
    substr = `${str[end]}${substr}`;
  }
  return substr;
}

function substring3(str, start, end) {
  return str.slice(start, end);
}

console.log(substring1("This is a string", 0, 4));
console.log(substring2("This is a string", 0, 8));
console.log(substring3("This is a string", 0, 8));
```

Be aware that `String.prototype.substr` is *not* `String.prototype.substring`